# How to fetch google analytics realtime activeUsers in php?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I downloaded API files from
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client
and tried below code...

```
$client->setApplicationName("Analytics");
$client->setDeveloperKey("key");
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

$optParams = array(
    'dimensions' => 'rt:medium');

try {
  $results = $service->data_realtime->get(
      'ga:profileid',
      'rt:activeUsers',
      $optParams);
  // Success.
} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
  // Handle API service exceptions.
  $error = $e->getMessage();
}
print_r($results);
```

It shows an error (401) Login Required'

When i tried the call from https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~rational-photon-578/apiui/api/analytics/method/analytics.data.realtime.get

I got the required realtime users belongs profileid.

So how can i implement a login process (Without going to google site) in this ?

I tried the below code...

```
$client_id              = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$service_account_name   = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location      = 'location of .p12 keyfile';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");

if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
$service_account_name,
array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics'),
$key
);

$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
$client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
} 

$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
echo $_SESSION['service_token'];
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);


$optParams = array(
'dimensions' => 'rt:medium');


try {
$results = $service->data_realtime->get(
  'ga:profileid',
  'rt:activeUsers',
  $optParams);
// Success.
} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
// Handle API service exceptions.
$error = $e->getMessage();
}
print_r($results);
```

Here i am getting the access_token and details...but the analytics data fetching fails because an error "Insuffient permission"

I got the results when i made test from google console with mentioned profile id.

Answer (score 3):

Accessing the Google Analytics API requires authentication.  It sounds like you would like to access your own data and not data owned by another user.  To do this you will need to create a [service account.](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

The php client lib on Github that you are using, has an example for using a service account you can find it [service-account.php](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/service-account.php)

The example uses the Boooks API.  You can change it to the Google analytics API by doing the following

```
$service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
```

change to

```
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
```

If you have any problems let me know and I will see if I cant give you a full example using Google Analytics with a service account.

**Note for others:**

At the time of this question the Real-time API is still in beta you have to request access.  Normally takes 24 hours to get access.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer.. it really helped alot :)
Now i am getting an error "Insuffient permission" for accessing the realtime users.

I tried below code
`code`
$optParams = array(
    'dimensions' => 'rt:medium');

try {
  $results = $service->data_realtime->get(
      'ga:123123123',
      'rt:activeUsers',
      $optParams);
  // Success.
} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
  // Handle API service exceptions.
  $error = $e->getMessage();
}
`code`

Comment: Realtime api is still in beta you have to request access.  Google it i don't have access to a PC right now.  Normally takes 24 hours to get access.

Comment: I added the email address ( got from service account) to analytics users account and given the permissions.
So it will take 24 Hours to get access for that email address ?

Comment: Actually I think it is your Google account the one that you use to make the app in Google app console but i am not sure.

Comment: I tried both email addresses.. but no luck.
Will wait some more time if there is any access delay from google service

Comment: Ok.. started to working... So i think there is a delay in approval of new email address belongs to service account.

@DalmTo , thanks for the suggestions provided.

Comment: Can we fetch google analytic data of any website by just using UA-1233 ID without any authentication ?.

Comment: I have just requested for the access. I have one query incase anyone above has tried. Can I access realtime of any user who has given token to me.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully display current data from my GA account to my website with php code below:

```
<?php

//Cloning Google API's
//git clone https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git

//Setting include_path in PHP.ini
//include_path = ".:/usr/local's/lib/php:/path/to/google-api-php-client/src"

//Alternatively, you can set the same ini directive dynamically in your code.
$lib_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/relative/to/DOCUMENT_ROOT/';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $lib_path . 'google-api-php-client/src');

require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';

$keyfile = 'path/relative/to/DOCUMENT_ROOT/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.p12'; // keyfile location   
$gaEmail = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com'; // email you added to GA
$gaAuth = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly';

// Create Client Object
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google_Analytics'); // name of your app
$client->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'); // from API console
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($gaEmail, array($gaAuth), file_get_contents($keyfile)));

/* Sample Grabbing Analytics data
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
var_dump($service->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts());
$response = $service->data_ga->get(
    'ga:87364223', // profile id
    '2014-09-01', // start date
    '2014-09-10', // end date
    'ga:uniquePageviews',
    array(
        'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
        'sort' => '-ga:uniquePageviews',
        'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=~/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+', // http://localhost/browse/style/3#showmoreexample url regex filter
        'max-results' => '25'
    )
);
var_dump($response);
*/

// Your analytics profile id. (Admin -> Profile Settings -> Profile ID)
$profile_id = 'ga:xxxxxxxx';
$start = 'yesterday';
$end = 'today';

try {
    $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
    $results = $service->data_ga->get($profile_id, $start, $end, 'ga:visits');
    echo $results['totalsForAllResults']['ga:visits'];
} 
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'There was an error : - ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```